# SQL cache dependency with WCF service

Tags: wcf

Can anyone tell me how to implement SQL cache dependency in a WCF service application which I'm planning to host on a IIS 6 server?

I have worked it our for web application, it works fine there. I want my WCF service to poll the database after every 5 minutes and get that data.

I have already enabled my database for query notifications. cant figure out a way to do this in WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

Caching with WCF http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230443.aspx check Sql Section

But i will also suggest to check below link, it list all the steps to do it. Exactly it is not the same as you needed but still can solve your problem to a certain extent.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46945/WCF-Cache

PS :-Read that System.Web.Caching.Cache class is not good to be used in WCF.

Comment: i have to use sql cache dependency, this is the requirement.

Comment: so lets say i have values in cache now..i'm following your first msdn link..how do i access them?

Comment: It is in the same way you do with Asp.Net  Try this link caching.http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2143/Caching-in-ASP-NET